# Error when Importing a .bacpac file

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm importing a .bacpac file into SQL-Azure and get the following error :

> Free Trial subscription is allowed to provision Basic, Standard S0, Standard S1, DW100, DW200, DW300 and DW400 database on server version 12.0'

I have a free subscription account, but as far as I can tell there are no limits with regards to importing databases. So what is this error saying?

Answer (score 2):

It seems there are some limitations with what you can do with free subscriptions.The same operation will succeed in Paid subscription..

Below thread also  talks about one more limitation.

> You can't enable stretchdb on free subscriptions

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6a0a6757-4298-419d-ab4c-e7f7db12042c/error-while-setting-up-stretch-db?forum=ssdsgetstarted

Comment: I was thinking the same and I had a chat with Azure support on twitter. They even suggested to file a call.

Comment: @Steef:great,if you could ask for all the limitations or ask for some documentation ,that would be great

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the princing tier from 'Basic' to 'S1 standard'

[image]